# Npgsql 6 mistakenly identifying 'timestamp' for 'timestamptz'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-6.0

After migrating from .NET 5 to .NET 6, i get the following error when inserting into the database:

```
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.
```

```
[2022-01-31 20:12:15] fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO database.table (timestamp)
      VALUES (@p0)
      RETURNING id;
```

I am using the following value converters to make sure all timestamps are still stored as UTC.

```cs
                var dateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
                    v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v.ToUniversalTime(), DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
                    v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc));

                var nullableDateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime?, DateTime?>(
                    v => v.HasValue ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(v.Value.ToUniversalTime(), DateTimeKind.Unspecified) : v,
                    v => v.HasValue ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(v.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc) : v);
```

The interesting thing is that the Postgres type of the field is not "timestamp with timezone" but "timestamp without timezone", which I verified in the database.

Setting

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

does not fix my problem, moreover I would not like to keep legacy behavious that is considered obsolote.

Any ideas on how to fix?

EDIT: Fixed it!

Seems the problem was caused by the fact the Npsql now defaults to `timestamptz` for DateTime fields when creating migrations. This was also assumed for existing fields since the type was altered for all fields when trying to create a migration. To fix my problem, I had to manually set the column type to `timestamp` for each DateTime field in my models.

Comment: The defaulting to `timestamptz` in the Npgsql EF Core provider isn't just a migration thing - it's a general change to type mapping (and affects things others than migrations). All this is documented in [the 6.0 release notes](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#detailed-notes), see also [this blog post](https://www.roji.org/postgresql-dotnet-timestamp-mapping) for more details and context.